# Need method to loop through numbers on another sheet and use as variables in loop

Tags: vba

I need to change the below code so that the numbers are pulled from a list on a different worksheet rather than included in the code. I need this list to be dynamic as numbers will be added to the list in the future.

```
For a = 1 To Lcell
   v = Cells(a, 2).Value
   If v = "1200" Or v = "652" Or v = "552" Then
       If Not RngDelFund Is Nothing Then
           Set RngDelFund = Application.Union(RngDelFund, Cells(a, 2).EntireRow)
       Else
           Set RngDelFund = Cells(a, 2).EntireRow
       End If
   End If
Next a
```

List on other worksheet

1200

652

552

+numbers to be added in the future

Comment: You can use either `Find()` or `Application.Match()` to determine whether the number in the cell exists in the list on the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the list is in column A of the other worksheet, crate a range object to *search* through, like so:

```
Dim rngToSearch as Range
Set rngToSearch = Worksheets("some_other_sheet_name").Range("A:A")
```

You can modify the `.Range("A:A")` portion of that to refer to any vector range on the other sheet (only 1 column *or* 1 row).  If it does not meet that criteria, then you'd have to use `.Find` method instead.  But usually lists are given either in row or column, so I'll assume that for now.

Then, to check whether `v` value exists in that range, just use the `Application.Match` function, which will return an error value if the match is not found, which you can trap like:

```
For a = 1 To Lcell
   v = Cells(a, 2).Value
   If Not IsError Application.Match(v, rngToSearch, False) Then
       If Not RngDelFund Is Nothing Then
           Set RngDelFund = Application.Union(RngDelFund, Cells(a, 2).EntireRow)
       Else
           Set RngDelFund = Cells(a, 2).EntireRow
       End If
   End If
Next a
```

Comment: Hello David, I don't want to change my range object as that will cause the code to run on the separate worksheet. I need something like this:

    v = Cells(a, 2).Value >>>>>

       If v = "Loop through list on other sheet" Then >>>>> 

           If Not RngDelFund Is Nothing Then